# How to add a change event to jquery slider after its initialization

Tags: jquery, events, slider

I am having a problem with jquery sliders' change event

I notice that if adding the response function during the initialization it works properly, for example:

```
s.slider({change: function(){....}});
```

However, if I wanna do it after its initilization, I cannot figure out how, apparently the following does not work:

```
s.change = function(){....}
```

Can someone please help me :-) Many thanks

Comment: jQuery UI creates new elements on initialization. `s` is probably no longer the element that needs to have the `change` event bound to it.

Answer (score 0):

If `s` is your selector here.. you can listen to the `slidechange` event after the slider is initialized.

```
s.on( "slidechange", function(event, ui) { .... } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your jQuery object is called `s`, you can add an event listener to it like so:

```
s.on( "change", function( event, ui ) {} );
```